# convert fibonacci indicator form pine to python

Tags: python, pine-script

I'm looking to find the relationships that govern this code in simple . I actually figured out how to find pivots. But I do not fully understand the function of the code. Can anyone explain this code simply? thank you.
Finally I want to convert this code to python
I have trouble finding the wave.
And I do not understand deviation and depth in this code .

(trading view pine script - auto fib retracement indicator - built-in)

```
//@version=4
study("Auto Fib Retracement", overlay=true)

// pivots threshold
threshold_multiplier = input(title="Deviation", type=input.float, defval=3, minval=0, inline = "Pivots")
dev_threshold = atr(10) / close * 100 * threshold_multiplier
depth = input(title="Depth", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1, inline = "Pivots")
reverse = input(false, "Reverse")
var extendLeft = input(false, "Extend Left    |    Extend Right", inline = "Extend Lines")
var extendRight = input(true, "", inline = "Extend Lines")
var extending = extend.none
if extendLeft and extendRight
    extending := extend.both
if extendLeft and not extendRight
    extending := extend.left
if not extendLeft and extendRight
    extending := extend.right
prices = input(true, "Show Prices")
levels = input(true, "Show Levels", inline = "Levels")
levelsFormat = input("Values", "", options = ["Values", "Percent"], inline = "Levels")
labelsPosition = input("Left", "Labels Position", options = ["Left", "Right"])

var line lineLast = na
var int iLast = 0
var int iPrev = 0
var float pLast = 0
var isHighLast = false // otherwise the last pivot is a low pivot

pivots(src, length, isHigh) =>
    l2 = length * 2
    c = nz(src[length])
    ok = true
    for i = 0 to l2
        if isHigh and src[i] > c
            ok := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < c
            ok := false
    if ok
        [bar_index[length], c]
    else
        [int(na), float(na)]
[iH, pH] = pivots(high, depth / 2, true)
[iL, pL] = pivots(low, depth / 2, false)

calc_dev(base_price, price) =>
    100 * (price - base_price) / price

pivotFound(dev, isHigh, index, price) =>
    if isHighLast == isHigh and not na(lineLast)
        // same direction
        if isHighLast ? price > pLast : price < pLast
            line.set_xy2(lineLast, index, price)
            [lineLast, isHighLast]
        else
            [line(na), bool(na)]
    else // reverse the direction (or create the very first line)
        if abs(dev) > dev_threshold
            // price move is significant
            id = line.new(iLast, pLast, index, price, color=color.gray, width=1, style=line.style_dashed)
            [id, isHigh]
        else
            [line(na), bool(na)]

if not na(iH)
    dev = calc_dev(pLast, pH)
    [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, true, iH, pH)
    if not na(id)
        if id != lineLast
            line.delete(lineLast)
        lineLast := id
        isHighLast := isHigh
        iPrev := iLast
        iLast := iH
        pLast := pH
else
    if not na(iL)
        dev = calc_dev(pLast, pL)
        [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, false, iL, pL)
        if not na(id)
            if id != lineLast
                line.delete(lineLast)
            lineLast := id
            isHighLast := isHigh
            iPrev := iLast
            iLast := iL
            pLast := pL

_draw_line(price, col) =>
    var id = line.new(iLast, price, bar_index, price, color=col, width=1, extend=extending)
    if not na(lineLast)
        line.set_xy1(id, line.get_x1(lineLast), price)
        line.set_xy2(id, line.get_x2(lineLast), price)


_draw_label(price, txt, txtColor) =>
    x = labelsPosition == "Left" ? line.get_x1(lineLast) : not extendRight ? line.get_x2(lineLast) : bar_index
    labelStyle = labelsPosition == "Left" ? label.style_label_right : label.style_label_left
    align = labelsPosition == "Left" ? text.align_right : text.align_left
    labelsAlignStrLeft = txt + '\n ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏ \n'
    labelsAlignStrRight = '       ' + txt + '\n ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏ \n'
    labelsAlignStr = labelsPosition == "Left" ? labelsAlignStrLeft : labelsAlignStrRight
    var id = label.new(x=x, y=price, text=labelsAlignStr, textcolor=txtColor, style=labelStyle, textalign=align, color=#00000000)
    label.set_xy(id, x, price)
    label.set_text(id, labelsAlignStr)
    label.set_textcolor(id, txtColor)

_wrap(txt) =>
    "(" + tostring(txt, "#.##") + ")"

_label_txt(level, price) =>
    l = levelsFormat == "Values" ? tostring(level) : tostring(level * 100) + "%"
    (levels ? l : "") + (prices ? _wrap(price) : "")

_crossing_level(sr, r) =>
    (r > sr and r < sr[1]) or (r < sr and r > sr[1])

startPrice = reverse ? line.get_y1(lineLast) : pLast
endPrice = reverse ? pLast : line.get_y1(lineLast)

iHL = startPrice > endPrice
diff = (iHL ? -1 : 1) * abs(startPrice - endPrice)

processLevel(show, value, colorL) => 
    float m = value
    r = startPrice + diff * m
    if show
        _draw_line(r, colorL)
        _draw_label(r, _label_txt(m, r), colorL)
        if _crossing_level(close, r)
            alert("Autofib: " + syminfo.ticker + " crossing level " + tostring(value))
            
show_0 = input(true, "", inline = "Level0")
value_0 = input(0, "", inline = "Level0")
color_0 = input(#787b86, "", inline = "Level0")
processLevel(show_0, value_0, color_0)

show_0_236 = input(true, "", inline = "Level0")
value_0_236 = input(0.236, "", inline = "Level0")
color_0_236 = input(#f44336, "", inline = "Level0")
processLevel(show_0_236, value_0_236, color_0_236)

show_0_382 = input(true, "", inline = "Level1")
value_0_382 = input(0.382, "", inline = "Level1")
color_0_382 = input(#81c784, "", inline = "Level1")
processLevel(show_0_382, value_0_382, color_0_382)

show_0_5 = input(true, "", inline = "Level1")
value_0_5 = input(0.5, "", inline = "Level1")
color_0_5 = input(#4caf50, "", inline = "Level1")
processLevel(show_0_5, value_0_5, color_0_5)

show_0_618 = input(true, "", inline = "Level2")
value_0_618 = input(0.618, "", inline = "Level2")
color_0_618 = input(#009688, "", inline = "Level2")
processLevel(show_0_618, value_0_618, color_0_618)

show_0_65 = input(false, "", inline = "Level2")
value_0_65 = input(0.65, "", inline = "Level2")
color_0_65 = input(#009688, "", inline = "Level2")
processLevel(show_0_65, value_0_65, color_0_65)

show_0_786 = input(true, "", inline = "Level3")
value_0_786 = input(0.786, "", inline = "Level3")
color_0_786 = input(#64b5f6, "", inline = "Level3")
processLevel(show_0_786, value_0_786, color_0_786)

show_1 = input(true, "", inline = "Level3")
value_1 = input(1, "", inline = "Level3")
color_1 = input(#787b86, "", inline = "Level3")
processLevel(show_1, value_1, color_1)

show_1_272 = input(false, "", inline = "Level4")
value_1_272 = input(1.272, "", inline = "Level4")
color_1_272 = input(#81c784, "", inline = "Level4")
processLevel(show_1_272, value_1_272, color_1_272)

show_1_414 = input(false, "", inline = "Level4")
value_1_414 = input(1.414, "", inline = "Level4")
color_1_414 = input(#f44336, "", inline = "Level4")
processLevel(show_1_414, value_1_414, color_1_414)

show_1_618 = input(true, "", inline = "Level5")
value_1_618 = input(1.618, "", inline = "Level5")
color_1_618 = input(#2196f3, "", inline = "Level5")
processLevel(show_1_618, value_1_618, color_1_618)

show_1_65 = input(false, "", inline = "Level5")
value_1_65 = input(1.65, "", inline = "Level5")
color_1_65 = input(#2196f3, "", inline = "Level5")
processLevel(show_1_65, value_1_65, color_1_65)

show_2_618 = input(true, "", inline = "Level6")
value_2_618 = input(2.618, "", inline = "Level6")
color_2_618 = input(#f44336, "", inline = "Level6")
processLevel(show_2_618, value_2_618, color_2_618)

show_2_65 = input(false, "", inline = "Level6")
value_2_65 = input(2.65, "", inline = "Level6")
color_2_65 = input(#f44336, "", inline = "Level6")
processLevel(show_2_65, value_2_65, color_2_65)

show_3_618 = input(true, "", inline = "Level7")
value_3_618 = input(3.618, "", inline = "Level7")
color_3_618 = input(#9c27b0, "", inline = "Level7")
processLevel(show_3_618, value_3_618, color_3_618)

show_3_65 = input(false, "", inline = "Level7")
value_3_65 = input(3.65, "", inline = "Level7")
color_3_65 = input(#9c27b0, "", inline = "Level7")
processLevel(show_3_65, value_3_65, color_3_65)

show_4_236 = input(true, "", inline = "Level8")
value_4_236 = input(4.236, "", inline = "Level8")
color_4_236 = input(#e91e63, "", inline = "Level8")
processLevel(show_4_236, value_4_236, color_4_236)

show_4_618 = input(false, "", inline = "Level8")
value_4_618 = input(4.618, "", inline = "Level8")
color_4_618 = input(#81c784, "", inline = "Level8")
processLevel(show_4_618, value_4_618, color_4_618)

show_neg_0_236 = input(false, "", inline = "Level9")
value_neg_0_236 = input(-0.236, "", inline = "Level9")
color_neg_0_236 = input(#f44336, "", inline = "Level9")
processLevel(show_neg_0_236, value_neg_0_236, color_neg_0_236)

show_neg_0_382 = input(false, "", inline = "Level9")
value_neg_0_382 = input(-0.382, "", inline = "Level9")
color_neg_0_382 = input(#81c784, "", inline = "Level9")
processLevel(show_neg_0_382, value_neg_0_382, color_neg_0_382)

show_neg_0_618 = input(false, "", inline = "Level10")
value_neg_0_618 = input(-0.618, "", inline = "Level10")
color_neg_0_618 = input(#009688, "", inline = "Level10")
processLevel(show_neg_0_618, value_neg_0_618, color_neg_0_618)

show_neg_0_65 = input(false, "", inline = "Level10")
value_neg_0_65 = input(-0.65, "", inline = "Level10")
color_neg_0_65 = input(#009688, "", inline = "Level10")
processLevel(show_neg_0_65, value_neg_0_65, color_neg_0_65)
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Explain this program to me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Most of all, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).